Mistmatching Checksums between CPP client and Cloudflare Worker
I'm trying to upload a file to cloudflare from an embedded device.
There a C++ application that generates a SHA-1 checksum before uploading the file
std::string generate_checksum(const std::string& file_path) {
    std::string test_file_path = file_path;

    std::ifstream file(test_file_path, std::ios::binary);

    if (!file) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Cannot open file for checksum.");
    }

    SHA_CTX sha1;
    SHA1_Init(&sha1);
    
    char buffer[8192];
    while (file.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer))) {
        SHA1_Update(&sha1, buffer, file.gcount());
    }

    unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    SHA1_Final(hash, &sha1);

    std::ostringstream result;
    for (int i = 0; i < SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH; ++i) {
        result << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(hash[i]);
    }
    
    return result.str();
}

The generated checksum is then stored in a database and the upload starts, Uploaded with santdard CURL settings (can prepare a code snippet if thats relevent?)
A worker processes the file upload and checks the checksum of the uploaded file against the checksum in the database
async function validateChecksum(fileContent, expectedChecksum) {
  const sha1Buffer = await crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-1", fileContent);
  const sha1Array = Array.from(new Uint8Array(sha1Buffer));
  const computedChecksum = sha1Array.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');

  return computedChecksum === expectedChecksum;
}

// handle upload method ...

    const url = new URL(request.url);
    const checksum = url.searchParams.get('checksum');

    const uploadStream = await request.body;
    const originalFileName = request.headers.get('X-Original-File-Name');

    const uploadResponse = await env.STREAM_BUCKET.put(`some-folder/${originalFileName}`, uploadStream);

    if (!uploadResponse) {
      await updateTransferStatus(site_id, camera_id, "FAILURE", env);
      
      return new Response(
        JSON.stringify({ transfer_status: "FAILURE" }), 
        { status: 500, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
      );
    }

    const uploadedFile = await env.STREAM_BUCKET.get(`${site_id}/${camera_id}/${originalFileName}`);
    const fileContent = await uploadedFile.arrayBuffer();
    const isChecksumValid = await validateChecksum(fileContent, checksum);

I was expecting the checksums to match but am brand new to this kind of task, what have I missed or not considered?
integrity is good; can download and open the file, the filenames are the same, the paths between client and cloud storage do differ but the filename is the same

The first step, use sha1sum console utility to verify the generated digests of your software.

ofc that was done and verified. But I already got an answer with a solution; on the c++ client the file is read from a buffer but on the worker crypto.subtle.digest reads the whole field is not able to do that without an extra library.
